# Диакритические знаки в итальянском алфавите

Tags: php

В итальянском алфавите есть буквы с диакритическими знаками: `à, è, é, ì, í, î, ò, ó, ù, ú`.

На входе строка, которая может содержать такие знаки, а может и не содержать.

Вопрос:
Как лучше заменить их на привычную латиницу (т.е. `'à'=>'a', 'è'=>'e'` и т.д.), не перебирая каждый знак?

Comment: `echo str_replace(['à', 'è', 'é', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ò', 'ó', 'ù', 'ú'],
                 ['a', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u'], 
                  'à, è, é, ì, í, î, ò, ó, ù, ú.');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = "à, è, é, ì, í, î, ò, ó, ù, ú";
echo iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $str);
```

Comment: Я заметил, что данное решение не всегда правильно работает, подскажите, от чего это зависит?

Comment: Нашел, перед конвертицией кодировки надо было указать, что работаем с итальянским языком. setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT');

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [`normalizer_normalize`](http://php.net/manual/ru/normalizer.normalize.php) с параметром `Normalizer::FORM_KD`. Это должно быть как раз каноническое решение проблемы. Только потребуется [пакет интернационализации](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.intl.php).